# Blender - Fill Up Bezier Curves

Tags: bezier-curves

I'm having a big problem with the bezier curves in Blender.
Im trying to fill up the curves, but i can't.
I have already saw some videos from youtube, telling that I have to clic on the 2D button.

[image]

But when i clic on the 2D button, this is what it happens.

[image]

I will really appreciate any help.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Suggest moving this to blender.stackexchange

Comment: Is that the Java logo?

Comment: exact duplicate. or deja vue

Answer (score 0):

Rotate the curve till is coplanar with global X-Y plane.

Than apply Rotation by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>.

Now you can set the curve to 2D.